# JIRA: How can i list down the tasks in which my name was mentioned in comment section?

Tags: filter, jira

JIRA: How can i list down the tasks in which my name was mentioned in comment section?

In JIRA, in many tasks i was mentioned in comment but not assigned that task to me. So, i want to create filter by which i can see the list of all tasks in which my name was mentioned in task. Do anyone know how to do this? thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of the JIRA you have.
In general the command to look in text field is:

```
TextField ~ "text"
```

where TextField is any JIRA text field like Description, Comment, Summary or it could be your Custom field name

more on the subject:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-Comments

Comment: Thanks @Hristo Bojkov..I am using JIRA v6.5-OD-03-002. Will this command work in this version?